# JS/Ajax Image upload- producing multiple image preview thumbnail of the same content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently working with an Image uploader([Source Files](http://dondedeportes.es/uploaderPreviewer.zip)). I am having difficulties creating duplicate preview fields. I am creating the preview image form but it is only displaying one thumbnail. How can i get the Js to give me two thumbnails? Here is a [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/) and further explanation to my source code

This what I initially want to do:
[image]

Snippet of JS for creating the preview Image forms(thumbnails)

**upLoaderPreviewer.js**

```
<script>
function createImageForm(index) {

    var form = '';

    form += '<div><table cellspacing="0">';
    form += '<tr><td class="label">'
          + '<label for="imageToUpload' + index + '">'
          + $.uploaderPreviewer.messages.imageLabel + ' ' + index + ':</label></td>';
    form += '<td class="removeImageButton">'
          + '</td>';
    form += '<td class="imageFormFileField">'
          // BUG: If the "enctype" attribute is assigned with jQuery, IE crashes
          + '<form enctype="multipart/form-data">'
          + '<input id="imageToUpload' + index + '" type="file" />'
          + '<input type="hidden" name="currentUploadedFilename"'
          + ' class="currentUploadedFilename"  /></form>'
          + '</td></tr>';
    form += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td>'
          + '<div class="previewImage" style="float:left; margin:10px 10px 10px 0;  "><img /></div>'
          + '<button type="button" class="small removeImage"></td></td></tr></table></div>';


    return form;
};
</script>
```

Comment: I can think of a quick fix ... you could duplicate the html when the image finishes loading

Comment: +1 That sounds like great idea. if you can put this in answer format I am willing to accept it. Thank you.

Comment: ok, let me see what can I do. can you make jsfiddle? that would help ;)

Comment: Thank you, I would do it in JSfiddle but it doesnt suppor jqueryUI. If you want a full explanation of the project files and live demo click on this [LINK SITE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

replace the function 'displayImage' on the uploaderpreviewer.js with this:

```
function displayImage($previewDiv, imageUrl) {
//New
var yourCustomPreview = $('#custompreview');

var imageFilename = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

$previewDiv
    .removeClass('loading')
    .addClass('imageLoaded')
    .find('img')
    .attr('src', imageUrl)
    .show();
$previewDiv
    .parents('table:first')
    .find('input:hidden.currentUploadedFilename')
    .val(imageFilename)
    .addClass('imageLoaded');
$previewDiv
    .parents('table:first')
    .find('button.removeImage')
    .show();

    //New
    yourCustomPreview.prepend('<img src="' + imageUrl + '"/>');
```

}

and add this where you whant to duplicate the thumb:

```
<div id="custompreview">
</div>
```

Comment: +1 this is perfect! Thank you! But one last thing, when I upload a second image it replaces the #custompreview of the first image

Comment: yes, but that has different solutions, you want to put it on differents places or one below the other?

Comment: For the duplicate preview pictures I would like it to be one picture below the other.

Comment: I accepted your answer. But Another issue came up: When I choose a picture it creates the duplicate(that part works fine), but when I decide to change that previous picture for another picture, the old duplicate is left inside the div `#custompreview`

Comment: of course, and if you delete someone will be still being there, that it is more work, also you would have to modify the method to eliminate

Comment: Alright my friend, I will try this on my own. If I am not able to achieve it, I migh ask a question about it, so please keep aware of . thank you

Comment: hey my friend, I worked on it all day and had nothing work. Here is the new question if you like to win more points: [STACKOVERFLOW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642961/ajax-js-image-uploader-creating-duplicate-preview-images)