# Ajax/Js Image uploader: Creating duplicate preview images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am working with an Ajax imageuploader from this [SITE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/). I currently achieve in creating duplicate preview images: one appears under the input field and the other will appear somewhere else in the page under something like "this what you chose". The problem is that if the user selects a file, the function will display the Image but if the user changes its mind and chooses a new image then the `yourCustomPreview` will show the new image chosen and the old.

Is there a way of just having the most recent preview picture shown without the old preview picture appearing? If unclear please check the source files [HERE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploaderPreviewer.zip)

**uploaderPreviewer.js- Original function**

```
<script>
function displayImage($previewDiv, imageUrl) {

    var imageFilename = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    $previewDiv
        .removeClass('loading')
        .addClass('imageLoaded')
        .find('img')
        .attr('src', imageUrl)
        .show();
    $previewDiv
        .parents('table:first')
        .find('input:hidden.currentUploadedFilename')
        .val(imageFilename)
        .addClass('imageLoaded');
    $previewDiv
        .parents('table:first')
        .find('button.removeImage')
        .show();
}
</script>
```

**uploaderPreviewer.js- Modified function**

```
<script>
    function displayImage($previewDiv, imageUrl) {
    //New
    var yourCustomPreview = $('#custompreview');

    var imageFilename = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    $previewDiv
        .removeClass('loading')
        .addClass('imageLoaded')
        .find('img')
        .attr('src', imageUrl)
        .show();
    $previewDiv
        .parents('table:first')
        .find('input:hidden.currentUploadedFilename')
        .val(imageFilename)
        .addClass('imageLoaded');
    $previewDiv
        .parents('table:first')
        .find('button.removeImage')
        .show();

        //New
        yourCustomPreview.append('<img src="' + imageUrl + '"/>');

    }
</script>
```

Comment: hey!! here I am! do you have an example with the "custompreview" working online?

Comment: @MCSI Hey! good to see you. Here is my working example online [SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/imageupload/index.php). As you will see the preview image does not update if you decide to change the original picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try this:

**TO EDIT:**

replace the displayImage function with this:

```
function displayImage($previewDiv, imageUrl) {
//New
var yourCustomPreview = $('#custompreview');
var imageId = $($previewDiv.context).attr('id');
var imageFilename = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

$previewDiv
    .removeClass('loading')
    .addClass('imageLoaded')
    .find('img')
    .attr('src', imageUrl)
    .show();
$previewDiv
    .parents('table:first')
    .find('input:hidden.currentUploadedFilename')
    .val(imageFilename)
    .addClass('imageLoaded');
$previewDiv
    .parents('table:first')
    .find('button.removeImage')
    .show();

    //New
    if(!yourCustomPreview.find('#' + imageId +'_prev').length > 0)
    {
      yourCustomPreview.append('<img id="' + imageId + '_prev" src="' + imageUrl + '"/>');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#' + imageId +'_prev').attr('src', imageUrl);
    }
}
```

**TO DELETE**

replace removeImage function with this:

```
function removeImage($removeImageButton, errorDisplayed) {

    var thumbIdToDelete = $removeImageButton.parents('table').find('[name=imageToUpload]').attr('id');
    var $parent = $removeImageButton.parents('table:first').parent();

    $.post($.uploaderPreviewer.removeImageAjaxUrl, {
        currentUploadedFilename: $parent.find('input:hidden.currentUploadedFilename').val()
    });

    $parent.find('input:hidden.currentUploadedFilename').removeClass('imageLoaded');
    $parent.find('div.previewImage')
        .removeClass('loading imageLoaded')
        .find('img')
        .hide();

    $parent.removeErrorMessage();

    if ( ! errorDisplayed) {
        $parent.find('input:file').val('');
        $removeImageButton.hide();
    }

    $('#' + thumbIdToDelete +'_prev').remove();
};
```

Comment: great! I feel part of your project haha

Comment: haha you are part of the project under the code if is ok with you I will put this `//Thanks to MCSI(http://stackoverflow.com/users/1013426/mcsi) for modifiying the code`

Comment: Hey my friend, I have updated the code to the [SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/imageupload/index.php). But another problem came, if the user deletes the preview image, the duplicate still shows under `This is the current picture you have chosen:`

Comment: Alright this works perfect now! Sorry for not clarifying that. You have solved this perfectly. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

whether is cache cause,

```
`yourCustomPreview.append('<img src="' + imageUrl+'?'+new Date().getTime() + '"/>');`
```

try this code;